# excelwings - repair file automatically to read file

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am working on excelwings to read an excel file.

However, the excel file is not something that I create. It is shared file used by multiple departments and it has some inbuilt formatting etc.

So, I don't disturb the existing formatting. So, I just plainly write data to that excel file and a specific sheet.

After I write data to the excel file, I use xlwings to read the file.

However, this results in an error.

But when I manually open the excel file, I get the below message.

[image]

Once I click `OK`, I get the below message

[image]

Once I click `Close`,my file name has the keyword `repaired`  and excelwings is able to read the file successfully (once file is repaired)

```
sales = xw.Book('format_test.xlsx') # works fine after file repaired
```

How can I suppress this error or avoid this issue and allow excelwings to read the file without me manually repairing the file?

If I don't repair the file and allow excelwings to read the file, I get the below error

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `corruptload` parameter in `Book()`:

```
import xlwings as xw

path = r"test.xlsx"

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    app.display_alerts = False
    wb = xw.Book(path, corrupt_load=1)

    wb.close()
```

You have to use the integer 1 as argument of `corrupt_load`, see [documentation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#book) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcorruptload).

Comment: When I use `corrput load`, I still get the pop up message (asking me to click close) but this is still better than me doing it manually.

Comment: I've added `app.display_alerts = False`, which supresses the pop up message.

Comment: FYI, corruptload not available on MacOs :P